# How to populate a JTextPane

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextpane

I have an array of string and would like to add them one by one to the `JTextPane`, each of which to be separated by a new line. How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create line with "\n| chars as separators. Second call

```
textPane.getDocument().insertString(textPane.getDocument().getLength(), theSumOfStrings, new SimpleAttributeSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for new line:

```
String separator = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : myStringArray) {
    sb.append(s + separator);
}
myTextPane.setText(sb.toString());
```

Edit: I found in an [old thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/335312/GUI/java/JTextPane-new-lines), that mentions the usage of the property [EndOfLineStringProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html#EndOfLineStringProperty), which makes sense, since the `JTextPane` extends `JEditorPane` which uses a document. I would give that a shot. Also, in the [JTextPane docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html), is written:

> For a discussion on how newlines are handled, see DefaultEditorKit.

Comment: The code above adds the text but does not place each string on a separate line.

Comment: @SolerMani - sorry to hear that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: After a bit off fiddling around with the code you gave me it eventually worked. Many thanks

Comment: -1, you should NOT be using the system property for the new line. Swing Documents use "\n" as a new line character no matter what platform you are using. One a Windows platform the "\r\n" string will be replaced with a "\n" anyway so your suggestion should work. However, it won't work for the reason you suggested which is why I downvoted. When you get the text representation of the Document, then the "\n" is replaced with the system new line property.